# how to Extract string between different characters, possible repeated clauses same line ? Using google sheets REGEXEXTRACT function

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Examples with 3 scenarios.

```
67fa9,extract this text;

f19b,extract this text,and this text with the comma or with out;

;f19b,extract this text,and this text with the previous comma or with out;;f4241c,extract this text which may contain a integer from 0-9;
```

I tried REGEXEXTRACT(A2,",.*?;"). however it doeasnt work for all scenarios in the column A.

see attached snippet of expected output.
[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: include expected output so we can manage to replicate what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your samples above and extracted the text you described.

Please see the output below if it matches your expected output:

[image: sample output]

I used this formula for all cells (regex is a little crude but does the job for all instances you mentioned):

`=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(<cell>, ";?\w+,([\w\s]+[,\w\s]+;?\s?;?[\w*]?[[,\w\s-]+]?);?"), ";\s;\w*,", ",")`

What I did was I extracted all then replaced the outputs you didn't specify with `REGEXREPLACE`.

So to explain the regex, the first one is `";?\w+,([\w\s]+[,\w\s]+;?\s?;?[\w*]?[[,\w\s-]+]?);?"`

As you can see, the pattern inside the parentheses `()` is the only one we are fetching.

`";?\w+,` - matches these patterns `;3f7f4de0,`
you can remove `?` if you are sure there is always a semi colon at the start, I added that due to your previous samples. `?` means the character before it can be there or not, which is the `;`

`[\w\s]+` - sentence before the first `,`, only `\w` (catches letters, numbers) and `\s` (spaces).

`[,\w\s]+` - sentence after the first `,` (this catches similar to the previous one but now, includes `,`, so it gets the consecutive sentences where there is `,` in the middle)

`;?\s?;?[\w*]?` - matches these patterns `; ;3f7f4de0,` you find in the middle part (i used `?` as you might have instances where it is only single semi colon or no space in the middle, at least it would catch them still. You can see a lot of `?` since they come and go.)

`[[,\w\s-]+]?);?` - matches the last sentence after the last `,`

I used `REGEXREPLACE` to remove the one we catched in the middle `; ;3f7f4de0,`. Since if we separate the `REGEXEXTRACT`, it will output to 2 cells. I used `REGEXREPLACE` to replace the unwanted string in the middle.

`";\s;\w*,"` - catch the pattern of `; ;3f7f4de0,`

`","` - replace `; ;3f7f4de0,` with just `,`

You can still optimize it by removing some unneeded `?`. I did that since the one you provided earlier was inconsistent, I need some leeway to match them all. But using the formula above as it is will still work on your recently posted sample data

Comment: Thank you, That solved it. can you elaborate the logic of the solution if possible. or how you tackled the issue.

Comment: hi @TAHIR, glad that it worked out on you. Anyways, I updated my answer since your 2 semicolons have spaces between them, the post above should be updated. will input the logic behind it in the post. will update you once that logic is added

Comment: @TAHIR, answer should now be updated with fixed formula and explanation of logic. Also included the recent data you provided.